# gradle build fails for unknown host exception

Tags: java, android, gradle

I just installed a new version of Android Studio and am trying to create a project using the built in templates.

My environment is:
Windows 7, SP1, 64 bit
In a secure domain environment and I am a domain administrator on my machine.

Here is what I am seeing:

```
C:\Users\stuz\AndroidStudioProjects\test>gradlew compileDebug --stacktrace
Downloading file://C:/Users/stuz/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.10-all.zip
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostExcep
tion: C
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:78)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: C
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.tryConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:65)
```

Comment: Looks like it's trying to ftp from "host" 'C' in file URL C:/Users/stuz/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.10-all.zip.  That's not going to end well.

Comment: I don't know if that's the problem, but local file URLs start with a triple-slash. Also don't forget to escape the colons in the properties file. Besides, I'm not sure why you would use a URL that points to `gradlew`'s own download directory, and whether this would work.

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me...

Find the file **gradlew.bat** on your project directory, in that file change **DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS** variable as below:

```
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=YOUR_HOST -Dhttp.proxyPort=PORT -Dhttp.proxyUser=USERNAME -Dhttp.proxyPassword=PASSWORD -Dhttps.proxyHost=YOUR_HOST -Dhttps.proxyPort=PORT -Dhttps.proxyUser=USERNAME -Dhttps.proxyPassword=PASSWORD
```

then run `gradlew clean build`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your **gradle/wrapper/gradle_wrapper.properties** file. I'm not sure how it happened, but you have an improper URL in there for the downloadable distribution of Gradle. Change that line from this:

```
distributionUrl=file://C:/Users/stuz/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

to this:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are on secure network - if that is the case than in your gradle/wrapper/gradle_wrapper.properties file

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

this line have **https** in it which is refused by secure network.
I changed to unsecure network and it started working for me.

Answer (score 0):

under you project folder go to :  platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js
find distributionUrl and Remove https with http and replace "services" with "downloads".

```
distributionUrl=http\://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to use the windows style file URI to make it valid

[Windows Reference for File URI](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/)

```
distributionUrl=file\:///C\:/Users/<your_path_separated_by_/_chars>/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score -1):

After changing the distribution url to http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip .

If you still get unknown host exception for services.gradle.org, try setting the HTTP / HTTPS proxy to your environmental variables . See the below post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59045565/4468693