# running flutter project for first time

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, sdk

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder-model:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:common:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:27.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:27.1.0 > com.android.tools:repository:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:27.1.0
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.72/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.72.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.72/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.72.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/7.0/asm-7.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/7.0/asm-7.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/7.0/asm-analysis-7.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/7.0/asm-analysis-7.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/7.0/asm-commons-7.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/7.0/asm-commons-7.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/7.0/asm-util-7.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/7.0/asm-util-7.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/jopt-simple-4.9.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/jopt-simple-4.9.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0.3.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0.3.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/6.0.3/proguard-gradle-6.0.3.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/6.0.3/proguard-gradle-6.0.3.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.squareup:javapoet:1.10.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve com.squareup:javapoet:1.10.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javapoet/1.10.0/javapoet-1.10.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javapoet/1.10.0/javapoet-1.10.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:4.1.0-6503028
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:27.1.0
> > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.10.0/protobuf-java-3.10.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.10.0/protobuf-java-3.10.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.10.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.10.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java-util/3.10.0/protobuf-java-util-3.10.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java-util/3.10.0/protobuf-java-util-3.10.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.crypto.tink:tink:1.3.0-rc2.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve com.google.crypto.tink:tink:1.3.0-rc2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/crypto/tink/tink/1.3.0-rc2/tink-1.3.0-rc2.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/crypto/tink/tink/1.3.0-rc2/tink-1.3.0-rc2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.flatbuffers:flatbuffers-java:1.12.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve com.google.flatbuffers:flatbuffers-java:1.12.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/flatbuffers/flatbuffers-java/1.12.0/flatbuffers-java-1.12.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/flatbuffers/flatbuffers-java/1.12.0/flatbuffers-java-1.12.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0-rc1.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0-rc1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite-metadata/0.1.0-rc1/tensorflow-lite-metadata-0.1.0-rc1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite-metadata/0.1.0-rc1/tensorflow-lite-metadata-0.1.0-rc1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.56/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.56/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.56/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.56/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/7.0/asm-tree-7.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/7.0/asm-tree-7.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve javax.inject:javax.inject:1.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0
> > Could not resolve javax.inject:javax.inject:1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:7.2.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:7.2.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:common:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:27.1.0
> > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/28.1-jre/guava-28.1-jre.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/28.1-jre/guava-28.1-jre.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.6.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:27.1.0
> > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.6.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.6/httpmime-4.5.6.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.6/httpmime-4.5.6.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:27.1.0
> > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.10/httpcore-4.4.10.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.10/httpcore-4.4.10.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:27.1.0
> > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.6/httpclient-4.5.6.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.6/httpclient-4.5.6.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.72.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.72.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.3.72/kotlin-reflect-1.3.72.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.3.72/kotlin-reflect-1.3.72.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr4/4.5.3/antlr4-4.5.3.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr4/4.5.3/antlr4-4.5.3.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve commons-io:commons-io:2.4.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve commons-io:commons-io:2.4.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:1.0.3.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:4.1.0
> > Could not resolve com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:1.0.3.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/1.0.3/juniversalchardet-1.0.3.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/1.0.3/juniversalchardet-1.0.3.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:27.1.0
> > Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.1.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:4.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:27.1.0 > com.android.tools:repository:27.1.0
> > Could not resolve org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.2.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.14.0
> > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-annotations/1.6.2/auto-value-annotations-1.6.2.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-annotations/1.6.2/auto-value-annotations-1.6.2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.1.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.14.0
> > Could not resolve com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.3.1/error_prone_annotations-2.3.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.3.1/error_prone_annotations-2.3.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.14.0
> > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/28.1-jre/guava-28.1-jre.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/28.1-jre/guava-28.1-jre.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.14.0
> > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.10.0/protobuf-java-3.10.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.10.0/protobuf-java-3.10.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.10.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.14.0
> > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.10.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java-util/3.10.0/protobuf-java-util-3.10.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java-util/3.10.0/protobuf-java-util-3.10.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta09
> > Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.60.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta09
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.60.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.60/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.60.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.60/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.60.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09
> > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/7.0/asm-7.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/7.0/asm-7.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09
> > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/7.0/asm-util-7.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/7.0/asm-util-7.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09
> > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/7.0/asm-commons-7.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/7.0/asm-commons-7.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.6.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09
> > Could not resolve org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.6.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jdom/jdom2/2.0.6/jdom2-2.0.6.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jdom/jdom2/2.0.6/jdom2-2.0.6.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.12.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:27.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:27.1.0 > com.android.tools:repository:27.1.0
> > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.12.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.12/commons-compress-1.12.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.12/commons-compress-1.12.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0.
> Required by:

```
     project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:27.1.0 > com.android.tools:repository:27.1.0
  > Could not resolve com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/jimfs/jimfs/1.1/jimfs-1.1.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/jimfs/jimfs/1.1/jimfs-1.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Please describe your questions, and mention the platform you are in and the versions you are using, so that you get better answers.

Comment: Are you connected to the internet? Because Gradle tries to build the project by downloading all the dependencies. I can see many "Could not resolve" issues in your log.

Comment: i am connected to internet, i am trying to build flutter project on android studio using the last verion of both

Comment: flutter_windows_2.0.4-stable

Comment: 4.1.3 for Windows 64-bit

Comment: can i just work offline? @ANUPSAJJAN

Comment: Initial setup needs internet connectivity to download all the dependencies, once you are done setting up, you can work offline for most of the time.

Comment: Did you add JDK path to your environment variable?

Comment: I suggest, you go to "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart" in your android studio, and retry.
Or toggle the gradle offline mode, "Android Studio > view > tool Windows > Gradle > click toggle offline mode" and then try building again.

Comment: do you mean c:\src\flutter\bin @ANUPSAJJAN

Comment: Attach you flutter doctor output

Comment: new error @ANUPSAJJAN

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
 va:173)
 a:367)
s
 org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)

Comment: Refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152406/exception-in-thread-main-java-net-unknownhostexception-services-gradle-org

Answer (score 1):

Try the following comments and check,

- Delete the build folder
- Run `flutter create .`
- Run `flutter pub get`

Comment: "My computer" is not a valid Dart package name.

See https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#name for more information

Comment: What is your application name? If it is "My computer", change it to the following format `demo_application` (use camel case and divide the words by using underscore keyword). then try the comments.

Answer (score 1):

**For newcomers to Flutter**

Basically `Could not resolve` issues in your log means you don't have proper internet connection. Try to download gradle using **VPN** services or download zip file from here [gradle.org/releases/](https://gradle.org/releases/) and put it in this path `C:\Users\/*Username of your laptop*/\.gradle\wrapper\dists` locally. then try to rerun your app. But first check your gradle version from this path in your flutter app `yourproject\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip // here mine is 5.6.2
```