# Issues running Flutter on Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:162)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:394)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:287)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:292)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:395)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:203)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1167)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:189)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1584)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This is the result I get whenever I try to run the Flutter demo app on my PC. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152406/exception-in-thread-main-java-net-unknownhostexception-services-gradle-org)