# I'm new to flutter and I always get error when I tried to run my first project on my physical device

Tags: flutter, android-studio

This is the error message I get. Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org

Comment: can you run this command: `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: maybe this can help [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152406/exception-in-thread-main-java-net-unknownhostexception-services-gradle-org)

Answer (score 0):

run `gradlew clean` and `flutter clean` then `flutter build`

Comment: how can i do that please

Comment: open your project, and navigate to terminal in the bottom-most pane, it consists of run, messages, etc. so find terminal there and input each code one by one

Comment: happy helping you!